# UPS Developer API Json. Getting Started

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ups

Can anybody help me please. I am trying to integrate with UPS and getting nowhere. I've opted to use JSon as I have had good success with that and hundreds of other websites/web-services

I have all the API documentation downloaded. What I am looking for is a worked example to get me going. Pretty much all the web-services I have used in the past give you worked examples showing what you need to do, what URLs to use, what data to send and what results you get back so you can experiment and understand their API.

With the UPS Api I can find nothing to help me out. I can find the stricture of the Json data to send and the structure for returned data. But nothing that's shows how it all goes together.

Can anybody point me in the right direction please. Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be a better question for the documentation site.

Answer (score 1):

UPS doesn't provide working examples because there are just too many platforms to support.  I've used the XML services to pull down shipment information.  UPS **does** provide an XSD for the services that I've used, as well as a URL to post my requests to.  (An XSD is an XML-based document that tells a developer how requests and responses need to be formatted.)

I'd be really surprised if you don't have something like this for whatever you're doing with JSON.  But you're going to probably have to do part of the work by trial and error.

Comment: I could use trial and error all day long but without knowing what the url format is I could be going for some time, hence my question here

Comment: Don't presume that the service you signed up for is a simple "URL format".   I don't get the idea that you've really read the documentation.

Comment: I've read the documentation and nothing jumps out at me which it usually does. Hence me asking my question here. Believe me if it were in the documentation I would have found it by now. XML there is lots of information on but I want to use json, because I have written my own libraries to handle json data (also using newtonsoft.json). @codenoir Your answer is of no help other than to suggest what I have already done. If you know something please share it.

Comment: I've managed to get this working through guesswork, trial and error. This at least gives me a bench mark for the rest of their API